# objective C - download image from server to iPhone and retain the date

Tags: objective-c, metadata, photosframework

We process a lot of photos - some are taken from iPhone and some our taken from our DSLR cameras. They all get uploaded to our Server.

our app allows downloading of media files (Photos and Videos) from our Server to the iPhone (All Photos folder and not app sandbox). When saving this downloaded image the date/time created of the image becomes the date/time when it was downloaded and saved on the iPhone and not the date/time when the image was originally created/taken from the DSLR.

How can I set the date of file to be the same as that on the Server.

The reason why this is important it because this will allow the iPhone Photos app to show the image along with other images that were taken at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update photo assets metadata date,location  with change request properties.

```objective-c
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    PHAssetChangeRequest *changeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:<#your photo here#>];
    changeRequest.creationDate  = serverDate
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {

    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks Ali! This looks promising. I'll try it and update SO.